# How does the OS resolve which NIC to send/receive on?

Tags: sockets, network-programming, winsock

My PC has two gigabit ethernet connections (NICs) - one on the motherboard, and one on a plugin card. I've never used multiple NICs before, and I'm simply not clear on how the OS resolves which NIC to use, and at what stage it occurs. Chance are "you don't have to know" because it happens automatically... but I'd still like to know - does it happen when you call the `bind()` function, for example, or later during a send or receive? Is it precisely the same process prior to both send and receive? Is it the same for TCP, UDP or any other protocol? Is it different between Windows and UNIX/Linux or Mac systems?

I'm motivated to ask because I have some Winsock2 code that "was working fine", but which stopped working when I reversed the order of the send and receive on a single socket. I discovered that it only received when there was at least one packet sent first.

I'm 99% sure there will be a bug somewhere, but I'd like to be 100% sure in the unlikely case that this is a "feature", or a bug beyond my code... because the symptoms are consistent with the possibility that the receive functionality is working fine, but somehow waiting to receive on the wrong NIC.

Comment: "only received when there was at least one packet sent first" ... if you're talking UDP, that could be caused by the internal firewall, or any external firewall that may be en route, or perhaps even by the network switch, if for some reason it thinks the MAC address belongs on a different port.

Answer (score 0):

It consults the IP routing tables to find the cheapest route, whuch determines the outbound NIC. This happens when you `connect()`. In UDP if you don't connect, as you usually don't, it happens on `send()`.

Comment: And is it exactly the same whether you're sending or receiving?